# Why does using excerpt_more filter change link location?

Tags: filters, excerpt

I added the following to my `functions.php` file in order to change the 'read more >' link that appears after `the_excerpt()` is called.

```
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'edit_more_link', 11 );

function edit_more_link() { ?>
        <a class="read-more" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>?template=iframe">read more &raquo;</a>
    <?php
}
```

The problem now is that the link is appearing before the excerpt text. Without the code added, the default link appears after the excerpt, which is what I want. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filters are for modifying values before they are output. Typically the function is passed some value where you can modify it or overwrite it, then pass the result back. Your link is appearing out of place because you're outputting the value directly, change it to `return` instead.

Also note that most template tags have versions that output their value, and ones that return. In your function `the_permalink` is changed to `get_permalink`.

```
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'edit_more_link', 11 );
function edit_more_link() {
    return '<a class="read-more" href="' . get_permalink() . '?template=iframe">read more &raquo;</a>';
}
```